# How to create a CHANGELOG.txt file for a Drupal project?

Tags: community-official-site

In the page [Commit messages - providing history and credit](https://www.drupal.org/node/52287) you can find some tips about the creation of the CHANGELOG.txt file, but there are many ways, even if you use the [Git Release Notes for Drush](https://www.drupal.org/project/grn) you will see many different formats. I can't find if there are a templates like the [README.txt template](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/documenting-your-project/readme-template) to do this.

Which is the correct way to create a CHANGELOG.txt file for a Drupal project?